# Is there a way to add/subtract all fields inside a JSON with another object with the same fields?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a Mongoose.js schema, which looks like this:

```
{
  "City": String,
  "Year": String,
  "Population": Number,
  "Blah": Number,
  "Nested": {
    "Something": Number,
    "More stuff": Number 
  }
}
```

Is there a convenient/best method to take two objects with these fields and add their number fields, or do I need to write a function to actually go in and do that?

I'm dealing with a very large schema here. If I write a function to do this, I'll have to manually maintain it; meaning if I change the schema, I'll have to manually change the member function I define to add stuff.

Comment: Destructuring may do what you want (I'm not sure if I get you right). https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment However, it's not introduced yet (ES6) :$

Comment: Can you provide two sample input objects and the output object you'd like to get? It's not clear to me what happens to the string properties, for example. Do they get omitted from the result?

Comment: Sorry, I realized I wasn't clear enough. I have edited the question slightly. I simply want to take two objects with the above format and add their numbers together.

Comment: You could avoid manually maintaining it by writing a function that iterates through each property of the object and if typeof === "number", check to see if the other object has that property (and typeof === "number") and add them together.

Comment: @LexJacobs I guess I could do that. So if I stumble upon an `object` type, I should traverse that and look for matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple. This is a generic calculation function that subtracts schema2 from schema1 and returns a new object.

It only does it for matching objects at the same level. if one schema has a property but the other doesn't it gets ignored. If they are numbers and valid numbers it's schema1 - schema2.

If they are objects, we need to go deeper.

In all type declarations schema1 is leading and assuming schema2 will follow. I horrible disaster and despair will await you in that case. It's up to you to test for all the types you want. I only built in a few safety measures.

```js
json1 = {
  City: "Amsterdam",
  Year: "2000",
  Population: 100,
  brutProduce: 10000,
  losses: {
    devalue: 10000,
    damages: 1000 
  }
}
json2 = {
  City: "Amsterdam",
  Year: "2003",
  Population: 100,
  brutProduce: 10000,
  losses: {
    devalue: 10000,
    damages: 1000 
  }
}

//Only calculate number types
function calculate(schema1,schema2) {
  var ret = {};
  for (var key in schema1) {
   if (schema1.hasOwnProperty(key) && schema2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       var obj = schema1[key];
       var obj2 = schema2[key]
       if(typeof obj === "number" && !isNaN(obj) && typeof obj2 === "number" && !isNaN(obj2)) {
         ret[key] = obj-obj2;
       }
       else {
         if(typeof obj === 'object' && typeof obj2 === 'object') {
           ret[key] = calculate(obj,obj2);
         }
         else {
           ret[key] = obj;
         }
       }
     }
    }
  return ret;
  }
test = calculate(json1,json2);
console.log(test);
```

```html
Please check console for the output. thank you.
```

#### Edit #1

Now what you might want to do after I've giving it a minute's worth of consideration, is to implement a custom type in your JSON that your schema traveller will recognize:

```
{ 
"customCalc":true,
"operation":"subtract",
"value":1000
}
```

Then when you find `typeof obj === 'object'` you can test for the existence of `customCalc` with a simple `hasownProperty`:

```
 if(typeof obj === 'object') {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty('customCalc')) {
        switch(obj.operation) {
            case 'substract':ret=obj.value-obj2.value;break;
            case 'add':      ret=obj.value+obj2.value;break;
            case 'divide':   ret=obj.value/obj2.value;break;
            case 'multiply': ret=obj.value*obj2.value;break;
        }
    }
    else {
       ret[key] = calculate(obj,obj2);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was about to write something _exactly_ like this on someone's suggestion. I'll test it out soon.

Comment: just hit run `code snippet` and check console ;-) you can see it neatly pulled everything down to 0.  Also I added an extra suggestion that might suit your needs