# Compare Two arrays for equality if they have nested objects in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two array with 5 objects each. Before I proceed, I want to check whether these two arrays are equal or not. I tried looking for the answers but unfortunately couldnt find anything for nested arrays with multiple objects.
Is there a way to achieve this?

eg.
Array1 ==> 5 nested objects[image]
Array2 ==> 5 nested objects

Now check whether Array1 == Array2 and return a boolean value.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself? if so show us the code

Comment: You need to compare the objects individually compare `index 0` to `index 0` compare all the `attributes` of each object for equality...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays-of-javascript-objects

Comment: Do the objects need to be in the same order?

Comment: You should define an equals method for your `objects`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript)

Comment: @depperm: YES, I did try but couldn't figure out a way.Thats why I came here for help.
   AreArraysIdentical: function (DefaultSortOrder, NewSortOrder) {
                var i = DefaultSortOrder.length;
                if (i != NewSortOrder.length) return false;
                while (i--) {
                    if (DefaultSortOrder[i] !== NewSortOrder[i]) return false;
                }
                return true;

            },

I am not able to browse through nested objects here.

Comment: @TimDev : Yes they need to be in the same order for equality condition to hold.

Comment: do you actually have nested obj or do you just have two arrays of 5 obj?

Comment: @depperm: two arrays with 5 objects each.

Comment: Array1 :
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
Array2 :
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object

Comment: have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666341/is-there-a-way-to-add-subtract-all-fields-inside-a-json-with-another-object-with/29666705#29666705 ? it would be fairly easy to modify for your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without jQuery - change them to a string by using globally available `JSON.stringify` method, then the comparison will be easy:

```
JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2);
```

This *is* kind of a hack. But it does work well. And in the era when Angular framework is checking it's injections by running `toString()` on its functions and then regexping the attributes (oh yes it does), I think this is just an effective solution ;)

Comment: Yes.. I read somewhere that it's not a good practice to convert them to strings. Don't know the reason though..

Comment: There's no such thing as a bad practice by default.  In this case it's an effective solution, in other cases it **might** be bad practice. My point being, it's subjective and entirely depending on the situation.

Comment: Yup.. Worked like a charm...  :)

Comment: It depends on your objects structure. The only downsides I know is that it wont be able to change date objects back from string values, and you'd lost eventual custom methods of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = [{val: 1}, {val: 2}, {val: 3}, {val: 4}, {val: 5}]
var arr2 = [{val: 1}, {val: 2}, {val: 3}, {val: 4}, {val: 5}]
var arr3 = [{val: 1}, {val: 2}, {val: 3}, {val: 9}, {val: 5}]

function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {

    // If the array lengths are different, return false
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;

    // Grab an array of true/false values determined
    // by the result of the `some` callback
    // Return false if `false` is found in the array, otherwise true
    return arr1.map(function (one) {
        return arr2.some(function (two) {
            return two.val === one.val;
        });
    }).indexOf(false) > -1 ? false : true;
}


isEqual(arr1, arr2); // true
isEqual(arr1, arr3); // false
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nyubfeLo/1/)